# Spring Data Rest validation for request with dynamic body

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-data-rest, json-ld

I am newbie to Spring related technologies.
I choose Spring Data Rest to implement a web annotation server. [According to the standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/annotation-model/), an annotation should be represented by JSON-LD, which means you can't bind the request to any of your domain object as the field names are changeable. (In C#, it is ok to bind it to **dynamic**). You just need to convert it to some-defined type before persisting to db.

Before converting it, I want to validate the request body.
I use:

```
@Service
public class AnnotationValidator implements Validator{

    @Autowired
    private Processor ldProcessor;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return AnnotationDocument.class.equals(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        Object processedAnnotation;
        try {
            processedAnnotation = ldProcessor.extractAnnotationModel(o);
        } catch (JsonLdError jsonLdError) {
            jsonLdError.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In *validate* method, the Object o does not represent the request body. Indeed, it tries to cast the request body to *AnnotationDocument*, so I cannot validate it.

Finally, my question is:
How can I process the pure request body and check its fields?
I solved my problem by creating *@RepositoryRestController* but I think it should be simpler way.

Comment: Can you link to "the standard" that explains these annotations? I've never heard of them and don't know how to model them.

Comment: Sure, https://www.w3.org/TR/annotation-model/ .All the fields change if the @context is different. That's the problem.